Transfomer model for implicitly learning text-based language style changes
I've been using Google's t5-small, but I want to improve.
Column A is a list of original sentences. Column B is a list of stylistically changed versions of those sentences.
Example:
column_actual
My name is George.
I love cheese.
I am cool.
column_changed
George, that be me. I am that.
Cheese is my biggest love cheese cheese cheese
How cool is me? Cool is that.
.... so, as you can see, the topics are all the same, but there is a style change.
Question

Is there a better model to use for this than t5-small, for a 'write like Yoda' supervised learning problem, where developing a model learns the 'rules' of changing the text from original to altered is the goal?


Define better! A seq2seq model is generally the right choice. You could try other pretrained versions or switch to FlanT5 or even one of decoder only foundation models like olmo. Your question is to unspecific for StackOverflow as it is currently written.
